# Variable in JavaScript and HTML tag from a MySQL while loop

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

How would I get a PHP variable in Java Script code in a php file? This code is inside a PHP while loop, so I know I have to somehow assign each JS attribute with an $id from the mysql result, and pass them to the input of the html, that way each of the html tags would be individual from each other.

Here is the PHP file code:

```
<script> 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
{
$id = $row['id'];

<select name='alarm_action' id="alarm_action" required>
    <option value="">Default Action</option>
    <option value='Play Sound'>Play Sound</option>
    <option value='Say This'>Say This</option>
    <option value='Run Command'>Run Command</option>
    <option value='Run Program'>Run Program</option></select>
<input name="file_path" id="file_path" type="text" style="display: none" required/>




<script>
var alarmInput = $('#alarm_action');
alarmInput.on('change', function() {
  var file_path = $('#file_path');
  file_path.show();
  switch ($(this).val()) {
    case 'Play Sound':
    case 'Run Program':
      file_path.attr('type', 'file');
      break;
    case 'Say This':
    case 'Run Command':
      file_path.attr('type', 'text');
      break;
    case '':
     file_path.hide();
    break;                      
  }
});
</script>

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
    <?php 

$id = $row['id']; 

?>
<!-- html  -->
<p><?php  echo $id; ?></p>
```

to add in javascript

```
<script>
//var id = <?php echo $id; ?>
var alarmInput = $('<?php echo $id; ?>');
alarmInput.on('change', function() {
  var file_path = $('#file_path');
  file_path.show();
  switch ($(this).val()) {
    case 'Play Sound':
    case 'Run Program':
      file_path.attr('type', 'file');
      break;
    case 'Say This':
    case 'Run Command':
      file_path.attr('type', 'text');
      break;
    case '':
     file_path.hide();
    break;                      
  }
});
</script>
```

So it's just use `<?php echo $id; ?>` inside the tag where you want to but don't forget to open and close php tags

Comment: how would I use it for the java script? Can you use php tags in JS?

Comment: Yes I will write a example

Comment: Okay thank you, I trued to just add php tags and it broke the JS code

Comment: how would I set the id  for this part of the code: var alarmInput = $('#alarm_action');

Comment: `var alarmInput = $('<?php echo $id; ?>');`  replace the #alarm_action to the php echo id

Comment: I need the alarm action, is there a way to append the '#alarm_action', so it is something like var alarmInput = $('#alarm_action_<?php echo $id; ?>'); Would that work?

Comment: Yes it should work but in case of numbers you need to concatenate the vars like 
var alarmInput = $('#alarm_action_+<?php echo $id; ?>');

Comment: that should give a result of something like: var alarmInput = $('#alarm_action_1'); Once it is calculated correct?

Comment: yes , test with your code like this 
var alarmInput = $('#alarm_action_<?php echo $id; ?>');  
it should work because it's being inside a string ''

Comment: so do I need the +?

Comment: don't need the + in this case because it's inside "" that means it's a string

Comment: I think I got that part working, still more work with my html and php code, but it looks like it works, thank you!!!